# Exception in thread "main" java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException on the jar file of my spark job

Tags: apache-spark, kubernetes, azure-aks

Running Spark 3..5.0 on AKS, i'm trying to run one of the example job that come with the Spark package, JavaSparkSQLExample to be precise and I get a NoSuchFileException when the driver pod starts, for some reason the it cannot find the jar file that is supposedly uploaded in the container. I used the docker file that is delivered with the Spark package to build the images:

```
#
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
#
ARG java_image_tag=17-jre

FROM eclipse-temurin:${java_image_tag}

ARG spark_uid=185

# Before building the docker image, first build and make a Spark distribution following
# the instructions in https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/building-spark.html.
# If this docker file is being used in the context of building your images from a Spark
# distribution, the docker build command should be invoked from the top level directory
# of the Spark distribution. E.g.:
# docker build -t spark:latest -f kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/Dockerfile .

RUN set -ex && \
    apt-get update && \
    ln -s /lib /lib64 && \
    apt install -y bash tini libc6 libpam-modules krb5-user libnss3 procps net-tools && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/examples && \
    mkdir -p /opt/spark/work-dir && \
    touch /opt/spark/RELEASE && \
    rm /bin/sh && \
    ln -sv /bin/bash /bin/sh && \
    echo "auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid" >> /etc/pam.d/su && \
    chgrp root /etc/passwd && chmod ug+rw /etc/passwd && \
    rm -rf /var/cache/apt/* && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*

COPY jars /opt/spark/jars
# Copy RELEASE file if exists
COPY RELEAS[E] /opt/spark/RELEASE
COPY bin /opt/spark/bin
COPY sbin /opt/spark/sbin
COPY kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/entrypoint.sh /opt/
COPY kubernetes/dockerfiles/spark/decom.sh /opt/
COPY examples /opt/spark/examples
COPY kubernetes/tests /opt/spark/tests
COPY data /opt/spark/data

ENV SPARK_HOME /opt/spark

WORKDIR /opt/spark/work-dir
RUN chmod g+w /opt/spark/work-dir
RUN chmod a+x /opt/decom.sh

ENTRYPOINT [ "/opt/entrypoint.sh" ]

# Specify the User that the actual main process will run as
USER ${spark_uid}
```

and here's my K8S configuration:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
  kind: Deployment
  metadata:
    name: spark-sql-proto-app
    namespace: spark-sql-proto
  spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
      matchLabels:
        app: spark-sql-proto-app
    template:
      metadata:
        labels:
          app: spark-sql-proto-app
      spec:
        nodeSelector:
          beta.kubernetes.io/os: linux
        containers:
          - name: spark-proto-app
            image: mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/mycustomsparkimage:latest
            command:
            - /opt/entrypoint.sh
            args:
            - /opt/spark/bin/spark-submit
            - --verbose
            - --master
            - k8s://https://sparkakscluster-dns-5i9mchtu.hcp.westeurope.azmk8s.io:443
            - --deploy-mode
            - cluster
            - --conf
            - spark.kubernetes.namespace=spark-sql-proto
            - --conf
            - spark.kubernetes.container.image.pullPolicy=Always
            - --conf
            - spark.executor.instances=5
            - --conf
            - spark.driver.memory=3G
            - --conf
            - spark.executor.memory=3G
            - --conf
            - spark.kubernetes.submission.waitAppCompletion=true
            - --conf
            - spark.kubernetes.driverEnv.HTTP2_DISABLE=true
            - --name
            - spark-proto-app
            - --conf
            - spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path=/opt/spark/work-dir
            - --conf
            - spark.kubernetes.container.image=mycontainerregistry.azurecr.io/mycustomsparkimage:latest
            - --class
            - main.java.org.apache.spark.examples.sql.JavaSparkSQLExample
            - file:///opt/spark/examples/jars/spark-examples_2.12-3.5.0.jar
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            ports:
              - containerPort: 8080
              - containerPort: 4040
              - containerPort: 9870
              - containerPort: 8088
              - containerPort: 8042
```

I tried applying this K8S configuration to my aks cluster and I expected it star all the required pods but driver pod fails at startup because of the NoSuchFileException.
I've tried several different values for the property *spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path* but the error is always the same.

Comment: I think my issue is very similar to the one described here: https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/spark-on-k8s-operator/issues/1474

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so I found out where I went wrong, I thought pods could exchange files directly. It is actually necessary to have a shared directory accessible from all the pods in your cluster so that driver and executors can upload and download the file of your spark job.
In my case since I'm working in Azure so I used an azure storage account and so the property *spark.kubernetes.file.upload.path* must be set to the following value: *abfs://storageContainer@storageAccountName.dfs.core.windows.net/*